# Why won't this string convert into a integer? Python

Tags: python-3.x

So I'm making a generic encryption program and I'm unbelievably stumped on this.

I'm passing the start of this function, `decrypt_func`, a variable `c`.

`c` is a string of numbers that I need to use as an integer. So I pass it through the `int()` function at the start to make it so I can use it. i get an error on the line `c = int(c)`. `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''`

I don't understand why this would be the error that I'm getting in this scenario, and I can't fix it. Please help me.
[My Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TcR2v.png)

Comment: I typed in your code, called your function "decrypt_func("121333", 2, 3)", and got no error. Your question seems incomplete.

Comment: if c == '' or d == '' or n == '' return false

Answer (score 0):

'' is an empty string, Python can't convert an empty string into a number.